# Get cell index of table onClick with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('.details').click(function(){
  $(this).index()+1).toggleClass('.details, .overlay-wrapper');
});
```

Each table cell has some details/content in (hidden). Whenever a user selects the cell I need to pass through the index so only the details/div within the cell is shown.

Every single cell in the table has a div/details within the cell. So I need to only toggle on and off the div within the correct cell. At the moment it toggles every single details div on the page.

Thank you

JsFiddle is below with the html.

http://jsfiddle.net/t6yczwuo/

Comment: Can you post your markup?

Comment: `$(this).index()+1)`  - `)` mismatch!

Comment: You are also *attempting* (invalid parameter) to toggle off the class used to connect the click event, which also indicates something is *not quite right* :) With HTML shown this is easy. Without, it is all guesswork. Please provide a sample of your HTML.

Comment: Your `toggleClass` call is incorrect too - they should be separated by space (no comma) and no leading `.` As @mattytommo suggested though, seeing your HTML would really help here.

Comment: could you provide HTML code snippet

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t6yczwuo/ I've updated my question and here is an jsfiddle that is loosely like my question. Sorry for the lack of HTML I provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with the code shown:

- Unmatched bracket
- Incorrect parameters for toggleClass (no `.` and no comma)

Without HTML this is all guesswork, but you seldom need the index to work with related cells. The following mockup use `closest()` to find the TD parent, then `find()` to find another related cell in the same TD:

```
$('.details').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("details overlay-wrapper").closest('td').find('.someother').toggle();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/gj2zz8po/

This example simply toggle the classes you specified on the details div, and hides/shows a related div within the same TD.

*If you use this JSFiddle as the start of your example we can customise the code to match your situation.*

Update for your new HTML:

```
$('.details-more').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('td').find('.overlay-wrapper .details').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/gj2zz8po/2/

Note: The `e.preventDefault()` should be used, even on bookmark links, to stop the page move to the top when clicked on a longer page.

Comment: I updated my question with an JsFiddle. However, I used your code snippet. With a few tweaks and it works! Thank you!

Comment: @Good Old Snoopy: I also updated mine to match your new Fiddle. See above. Cheers

Comment: One thing that i've noticed is. Once i've clicked the element that the `onClick` is attached too. The element disappears.  Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: That was the initial `toggleClass`. Removed now from the example as you apparently only want to toggle the other div :)

Comment: Thanks dude, appreciate your help. I seen where I went completely wrong now :p

I'll mark your answer correct soon. I'll just keep it open for a short time see if anyone debates other methods :)

Comment: @Good Old Snoopy: Note this does not require the `details` class at all, except to locate the `div` to toggle. The actual hide/show can be done with toggle alone (no need for `toggleClass()`).

Answer (score 1):

You need `.next()` and not `index()`.

`.toggleClass()` accepts just a single class name without a `.`. Also, toggling the class on which you are using any kind of selector is not recommended.

```
$('.details-more').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.overlay-wrapper').find('div').toggleClass('details');

    //Instead of find('div') you could use a specific class selector - 
    //find('.targetHidden') provided this class remains static throughout the html.
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6yczwuo/5/)**

Comment: It is generally more "robust" to avoid `next()` and `prev()` and instead use `closest()` and `find()` together. They allow for the DOM layout to change without breaking so easily.

Comment: Point taken. My point was just to show `index()+1` is a wrong method here; logically that equals `next()`.

Comment: XY questions... Figure out what they actually want/need, not what they ask for :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Header</td>
    <td>Header</td> 
    <td>Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="details-more">Details</a>
        <div class="overlay-wrapper details">
            <div class="">THIS IS THE SOME DETAILS OR CONTENT</div></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="details"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="details-more">Details</a>
        <div class="overlay-wrapper details">
            <div class="">THIS IS SOME MORE CONTENT</div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="details"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="details-more">Details</a>
        <div class="overlay-wrapper details">
            <div class="">SOME TEST RANDOM STUFF</div></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="details"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="details"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="details"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="details-more">Details</a>
        <div class="overlay-wrapper details">
            <div class="">SOME MORE CONTENT</div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="details"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="details"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="details"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}

.details {display:none;}
```

Javascript

```
$('.details-more').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.overlay-wrapper').toggleClass('details');
});
```

Comment: Best to provide the code and explanation here too. Otherwise no one may bother to look to see what you fixed :)

Comment: is it fine @TrueBlueAussie